# Имя конструктора объекта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, вопрос исключительно в познавательных целях:

```
var DomAPICanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var jQueryCanvas = $("<canvas>");

console.log(DomAPICanvas.constructor); // HTMLElementCanvas function
console.log(jQueryCanvas.constructor); // JQuery function
```

Собственно я прекрасно понимаю, почему `jQueryCanvas.constructor` ведет себя именно таким образом (chaining), меня интересует следующее: есть ли возможность получить настоящее значения конструктора? И если да, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настоящее значение конструктора можно получить только имея доступ к оригинальному обьекту/элементу. ( `$("<canvas>")[0]` )

То есть код будет выглядеть так:

```
var DomAPICanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var jQueryCanvas = $("<canvas>");

console.log(DomAPICanvas.constructor); // HTMLElementCanvas function
console.log(jQueryCanvas[0].constructor); // HTMLElementCanvas function
```

Comment: либо

     jQueryCanvas.get(0).constructor